# Don't understand a percentage word problem - 40% more than equation

Tags: percentages

https://www.jobtestprep.co.uk/shl-numerical-test-answers#numericalsample

I don't understand the logic behind how to get the answer in SHL Numerical Reasoning Test Question 4 - Graphs and Tables #3

Specfically this part of the answer:
The Northern region produced 40% more Referrals than the Southern region.

Or in the form of an equation:

(I) NR = 1.4 x SR

We already know the total number of referrals:

(II) NR + SR = 180

Plugging (I) into (II):

2.4 x SR = 180

SR = 75

NR = 105

I'm lost what happens after you plug in I into II and how 2.4 is calculated. I'm guessing it has something to do with fractions but I'm stumped.

Comment: $1.4s+1s=2.4s$, and $s=\frac{180}{2.4}=75$.

Comment: @Nij how did you get 1.4s + 1s?

Comment: That's literally the substitution you made, I into II.

Comment: We have $NR+SR=1.4\cdot SR+SR=(1.4+1)\cdot SR=2.4\cdot SR$

Comment: @Peter the part I'm confused on is are the steps between the 2nd and 3rd step. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the confusion. Plugging in I into II just means to replace "$NR$" by "$1.4\cdot SR$". We then only have one variable and can easily solve the resulting equation. Or are you confused why we have $1.4$ ? According to the question , this is not the case. And then, we just use the distributive law to add $1.4\cdot SR$ with $SR$ (which we can write as $1\cdot SR$) as I have shown in the above comment.

Comment: @Peter thank you I just figured it out. I got confused for some reason and it just didn't make sense to me for some reason but now it's very clear.

Comment: Nice that I could help.

Comment: @Peter I think the part I got confused with was the distributive law when 1.4 * SR + SR = 180 which is equals to (1.4 * SR) + (1 * SR) = 180. Is this correct?

Comment: I think, the confusing part was that there is no "$1$" in "SR"

Comment: @Peter I apologize if this sounds stupid but I'm confused why it's 2.4 x SR = 180 and not 2.4SR = 180. Wouldn't it be (1.4 * SR) + (1 * SR) = 180, equals 1.4SR+ SR = 2.4SR = 180, and then SR = 75? Am I getting the order of operations wrong?

Comment: We can omit the multiplication signs. In fact, we have to divide $180$ by $2.4$ to get SR. So what you did in the last comment is exactly what you have to do. Everything OK.

Comment: @Peter Okay great. I think my hang up was the way it was written in the original example. For some reason it threw me off and I got confused. Thank you and everyone else for your help.